# Function which executes when the date changes

Tags: python, event-handling

I need a function to execute every time the date changes. Currently I'm checking in a loop to see if the date changed, but I'm looking for a more effective method....in Python

Any help appreciated

Comment: Have you considered using a cron job to accomplish this and just run the program periodically?

Comment: what OS are you using?

Comment: Raspbian Wheezy on my RPi

Answer (score 2):

What you really want to do is *schedule* a function to be run at a certain time. You need to do this with a *scheduling* mechanism. You could, of course, write one yourself, but probably the best way to go would be to use a library that does this for you.

`APScheduler` is a very mature good library for just this sort of thing.

Docs: http://apscheduler.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Pypi: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/APScheduler/3.0.0

## Example

Here is a quick little example

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BlockingScheduler

scheduler = BlockingScheduler()

@scheduler.scheduled_job('interval', seconds=5, timezone='UTC')
def hello():
    print('Hello!')

scheduler.start()
```

This will run the function `hello` every five seconds. You can change `seconds=5` to `days=1` to have it run once a day. There is *much* more configuration you can do, so you'll probably want to read the documentation. It is able to express just about any date time format you could want, including `cron`.

It also supports different types of schedulers, for instance I chose a `BlockingScheduler` because wanted the entire program to run as a function of the scheduling mechanism (so you could try this out easily on your own system). You can also use, for instance, a `BackgroundScheduler` which will allow you to schedule tasks from within your program in an efficient manner that will not block the main thread (fixes your going in a loop forever problem).

Comment: Thanks apscheduler running as Background Scheduler is working perfectly!

Comment: @FrancoisWattel I am glad it is working for you. If you find this answer to be correct, please accept it.